# Function adding eventlistener to node not working

Tags: javascript

This function below is not working. I have an original object which is a square. I duplicate that square using appendChild. In that duplication method I call this function below to add an eventlistener to the newly created clone of the square. The elem parameter is the cloned node. Why does the function below not work?

```
function addEventListenerToNode(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click",function() {
    object.createOutline(elem);
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Who's calling this function? What is `object.createOutline`? Where is the HTML? Code samples are more helpful when you don't have undefined variables/methods

Comment: What's the value of `object`? Add `console.log(object);` to the function to see what it is.

Comment: `appendChild()` wont doublicate, but move the element

Comment: elem is the original element. 

var clone = elem.cloneNode();
elem.appendChild(); 
addEventListenerToNode(clone); 

This for some reason does not work, still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Typo: You are missing an `e` in the word listener. You should see an error in your console.

```
elem.addEventListner("click",function() {
    object.createOutline(elem);
});
```

Should be

```
elem.addEventListener("click",function() {
    object.createOutline(elem);
});
```

Comment: No, the misspelling only came to existence when i wrote this post. The original code does not have that problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DanielAbella Hard to have  other ideas when you are not showing enough code.

Comment: I should have phrased by question better. I was actually wondering whether it should work. In which case you've already answered by question. Thank you!